# Excel/VBA - Userform overwriting existing data

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I have written a user form for staff to input data on items confiscated, print out copies of said form and save all data inputted.

This has worked well for the 2 years, but the universe has now supplied me a bigger and better idiot. Apparently Rows were deleted from the worksheet so that someone could return items to a person without leaving any record.

Now - any data input to the form overwrites previous lines. Each new input overwrites another line higher(older). I am using  the following lines to find next empty row and enter data on work sheet. It was writing 5 rows of the same data, as the code below was now written 5 times in a row.

I can not see where the error is - or understand how deleting Rows on worksheet would have the effect it has or change the code on the userform?

```
' WRITE DATA TO SPREADSHEET    

emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("F:F")) + 1

RowCount = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2")
.Offset(emptyRow, 0).Value = Me.txtSurname.Value
.Offset(emptyRow, 1).Value = Me.numCRN.Value
.Offset(emptyRow, 2).Value = Me.cboUnit.Value
.Offset(emptyRow, 3).Value = DateValue(Me.txtDateConf.Value)
.Offset(emptyRow, 4).Value = Me.numBoxnum.Value
.Offset(emptyRow, 5).Value = Me.txtItem6.Value
.Offset(emptyRow, 6).Value = Me.txtItemDesc6.Value
.Offset(emptyRow, 7).Value = Me.numQTY6.Value
.Offset(emptyRow, 8).Value = Me.cboCondition6.Value
.Offset(emptyRow, 9).Value = Me.cboReason6.Value
If Me.chkHistCheck6.Value = True Then
.Offset(emptyRow, 10).Value = "Yes"
Else
.Offset(emptyRow, 10).Value = "No"
End If

If Me.chkHistCheck6.Value = "" Then
    .Offset(emptyRow, 10).Value = "No"
End If

.Offset(emptyRow, 11).Value = Format(Now, "dd/mm/yyyy hh:nn:ss")
End With
```

Comment: Don't rely on `CountA` to find the last used row.  It's commonly recommended to use `Range.End(xlUp)`, so in your case: `emptyRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row + 1`

Comment: And then instead of Offsetting to the emptyRow, just work with it directly: `With Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(emptyRow, "A")` and then your Offset lines become `.Offset(, 0)...  .Offset(, 1)....` etc

Comment: Or, if you are like me, and can never remember how many columns a column is offset from column A, you can use `With Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(emptyRow, "A")` (or just `With Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(emptyRow)`) and replace the offsets with `.Cells(1, "A").Value = ..`, `.Cells(1, "B").Value = ..`, `.Cells(1, "C").Value = ..`, etc.

Comment: There seems to be nothing wrong with your code. However, I would guess you may have a gap in your column "F:F", used as range in in `WorkSheetFunction.CountA`. Make sure you don't have any empty cell in between the header and the last cell (bly simply using `Ctrl + Arrow Up/Down`).

Comment: As another alternative, run the code `WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("F:F")) + 1` in the VBA Immediate Window (`Ctrl + G`) and check if the result matches with the correct row index in your worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry All for delayed response. We have figured that the code, whilst clunky, was still fine but there was some memory issue at play.

The work sheet being written to was at 1400 lines, with 2 years of data inputs. Discovered that if we simply archived (cut and pasted) that all out to a new file the form and worksheet ran flawlessly again.

Sure someone here would have figured it out in seconds on looking at the whole file but sharing the data or evening the whole code was a no-no. Thanks for your time all.